# Previewing image before uploading?

Tags: javascript, image, file-upload

Is there a way to preview a picture on the html page, before uploading ito the server?

I need to show the preview of an image that I still need to upload, just to show that there were changes made. I just probably need to change the image source. Are there any existing techniques/methods that I could use?

Comment: Safari provides you some option for that but I am also looking for other browsers by HTML like IE, Chrome and FF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem recently like this:

I binded a changelistener to the fileinput

```
<input type="file" name="photofile" id="photofile">



$('#photofile').bind("change", function(){
            readUrl(this);
         });
```

and set the image in the readURL function to a previously empty img element like this:

```
readUrl = function(input) {
        //if File is there
        if(input.files && input.files[0]) {
            //create a Filereader
            var reader = new FileReader();
            //bind a function to the reader which will be executed when file is completely loaded
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                //Here you render your preview image
                $("#bild-vorschau").attr("src", e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

Here you can see it in a [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bALkx/)

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved using `The HTML5 FileReader API`

Using only JavaScript and the FileReader object, we can allow the user to load images into an application.

HTML code:

```
<input type="file" id="getimage">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Your image here</legend>
            <div  id="imgstore"></div>
    </fieldset>
```

JavaScript code:

```
<script>
function imageHandler(e2) 
{ 
  var store = document.getElementById('imgstore');
  store.innerHTML='<img src="' + e2.target.result +'">';
}

function loadimage(e1)
{
  var filename = e1.target.files[0]; 
  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = imageHandler;  
  fr.readAsDataURL(filename); 
}

window.onload=function()
{
  var x = document.getElementById("filebrowsed");
  x.addEventListener('change', readfile, false);
  var y = document.getElementById("getimage");
  y.addEventListener('change', loadimage, false);
}
</script>
```

How To Check If Browser Supports HTML5 File API:

```
// Checking all the possible window objects needed for file api
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
  // Browser is fully supportive.
} else {
  // Browser not supported. Try normal file upload
}
```

Useful ref links below:

[Demo Here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api)

[Complete Example Here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api)

[Compatibility tables for support of HTML5, CSS3, SVG and more in desktop and mobile browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this article [Ajax Upload with Progress Bar](http://webomnizz.com/blog/jquery/ajax-upload-with-progress-bar-in-jquery/) and try the demo which that you want to achieve on your question. [DEMO](http://webomnizz.com/demo/ajax-upload-with-progress-bar/)

This is possible by [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) which is working on modern browsers.